Snapshot keep property is not working for iceberg
I have set history.expire.min-snapshots-to-keep = 6 and still I am getting only one snapshot from snapshot metadata table for iceberg table
Is there any other property I am missing to have multiple valid snapshots?

history.expire.min-snapshots-to-keep should be sufficient, for basic scenarios. Do you have any more details, or reproducible example perhaps?

Nessie is designed to apply the "git" ideas to managing Iceberg tables. It maintains a full commit graph of changes. However, when the Iceberg metadata is access via the Iceberg REST Catalog API Nessie returns only the snapshot that corresponds to the current commit.
The rationale is mainly two-fold: 1) reduce the amount of data that has to be processed for each request 2) avoid confusion, since in Nessie the commit graph is a DAG, but only linear snapshot history can be expressed in Iceberg metadata JSON.
If accessing older snapshots is required (e.g. for time travel) Nessie provides way to fetch them by using a custom prefix in the Iceberg REST API URI (but that's is a different topic, I guess).
